# Laravel Passport consuming own API fail

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-passport

I'm building a SPA with Vue. My front-end and my back-end (Laravel) are in the same codebase. I want to approach my API (that is in my back-end) via the Laravel Passport Middleware *CreateFreshApiToken*. I'm approaching my sign in method in my *AuthController* via *web.php*.

**My problem:**
As soon as I'm successfully signed in via my sign in method I would expect that at this time Passport created the *laravel_token cookie*. This is not the case. The cookie is created after a page refresh. But as I said I'm building a SPA and that's why I don't want to have page refreshes.

**What I want:**
I want to sign in via my sign in method then use the Passport *CreateFreshApiToken* middleware. After that I want to use the (just created in the middleware) *laravel_token cookie* so that I can correctly and safely speak to my own API in my signed-in section of the SPA.

**More information:**

*Kernel.php*

```
// Code...
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // other middlewares...
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],
];
// Code...
```

*AuthController.php*

```
// Code...
public function login()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')], true)) {

        return response()->json([
            'user' => Auth::user(),
            'authenticated' => auth()->check(),
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json(['authenticated' => false], 401);
}
// Code...
```

*Login.vue*

```
// Code...
methods: {
    login: function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        this.$http.post(BASE_URL + '/login', {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
        })

        .then(function (response) {

            localStorage.user_id = response.body.user.id;

            router.push({
                name: 'home'
            });
        });
    },
},
// Code...
```

**What goes wrong? This:**

*CreateFreshApiToken.php*

```
// Code...
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $this->guard = $guard;

    $response = $next($request);

    // I'm signed in at this point

    if ($this->shouldReceiveFreshToken($request, $response)) { // returns false unless you refresh the page. That's why it won't create the laravel_token cookie
        $response->withCookie($this->cookieFactory->make(
            $request->user($this->guard)->getKey(), $request->session()->token()
        ));
    }

    return $response;
}

protected function shouldReceiveFreshToken($request, $response)
{
    // both methods below return false
    return $this->requestShouldReceiveFreshToken($request) &&
           $this->responseShouldReceiveFreshToken($response);
}

protected function requestShouldReceiveFreshToken($request)
{
    // $request->isMethod('GET') - returns false because it's a POST request
    // $request->user($this->guard) - returns true as expected
    return $request->isMethod('GET') && $request->user($this->guard);
}

protected function responseShouldReceiveFreshToken($response)
{
    // $response instanceof Response - returns false
    // ! $this->alreadyContainsToken($response) - returns false as expected
    return $response instanceof Response &&
                ! $this->alreadyContainsToken($response);
}
// Code...
```

I assume it is possible what I want to achieve right? If yes, how?

Comment: Anyone? I'm really stuck...

Comment: Can anyone help me? I've tried everything... I asked it on Laracasts too but still no answers...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, decided to stick to client_secret way. I guess it's not relevant for you now, but I've found 2 ways of receiving the laravel token without refresh:

1) sending dummy get request with axios or $http, whatever you use - token will get attached to response;

2) changing requestShouldReceiveFreshToken method in CreateFreshApiToken.php - replace `return $request->isMethod('GET') && $request->user($this->guard);` with `return ($request->isMethod('GET') || $request->isMethod('POST')) && $request->user($this->guard);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function consumeOwnApi($uri, $method = 'GET', $parameters = array())
{
    $req = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create($uri, $method, $parameters, $_COOKIE);
    $req->headers->set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', app('request')->session()->token());
    return app()->handle($req)->getData();
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation how to implement and use the code.